# Clever solutions for average-upscale multi-image super resolution of a scene with various "depths"

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, homography, disparity-mapping

I'm working on a side project with a 4 camera system arranged in a 2x2 grid. The cameras are spaced about 1.5" apart, and take images simultaneously. With this system, I create a roughly 52MPix image from four 13MP images. This is all done with OpenCV, Gstreamer, and ubuntu 18.04.

This is achieved by aligning all four images using homography, averaging the images, and upscaling.

The results are really great for those objects within the homography plane! See a screencap here:

[image: 1]

If you look closely however, my 3D printer in the bottom right has some "ghosting" because the homography was using features from the poster. When the images are averaged, the poster is well aligned, but the 3D printer at a closer depth is not.

I'm looking to see if folks have any creative solutions to make this work for items of all depths.

Here are some attempts so far:
1.I have tried using disparity map to identify various depth planes and have a homography for each, but my baseline between cameras is apparently too small to make a nice disparity image.
2. Using a blur-finding metric to identify regions of the image that have the ghosting problem (working on this now)

Comment: How about finding areas, after aligning, where the colors are obviously different? But I don't see how averaging the images will help you increase resolution.

Comment: perspective homograpgy is only correct for either a planar scene or a pure rotation around the projection center. If you are using keypoint matching you could identify keypoints on that object to be outliers after homography computation. Maybe you could use some kind of "stereo matching", too.

Comment: A bit of an update: I dividing the image into blocks and looking for areas of "blur" didn't work as repeatably as I wanted too to "detect" objects that have the ghosting problem. I did discover this though: [OpenCV Mapping Classes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/db/d61/group__reg.html) This is a pixelwise registration "toolbox" within opencv. Unfortunately there is nearly 0 documentation, and any questions asked about it here on Stack are almost universally left empty. Last night I created the workflow, but didn't seem to have any results. I'll crank on it today.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the average->upscale is the simplest superresolution approach on a bench of many. I'm just using it to start. You'd be surprised how well it works. I cut the warped images up into chunks for individual processing to take advantage of multiple threads so I can quickly implement your idea of comparing colors between the warped images for each chunk. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Alright folks, I've got a working but "hacky" solution thanks to a push by @CrisLuengo. I use feature matching and homography to warp 3 images to the perspective of image 0. I then cv2.absdiff(img0,imgN). I create a mask by '&' all three diff images, and in the diff zones (spots where the overlap is not good) I pull pixels from image 0 only. It creates a locally low-rez zone, but looks like a complete image!